# Why won't my escape key work in the keybindings?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm having this really strange problem that I just can't seem to figure out. My escape key won't bind. In fact, the option for using the escape key is simply grayed out in the keybindings menu:

[image: diablo3menu]

I can't bind or unbind the escape key at all. Though it's not necessary to use the escape key, it's driving me crazy. I use this key to log out of the game and to clear menus from the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: So what exactly is the issue?  Escape isn't clearing dialogs and bringing up the game menu? Or you want to use escape for something else?

Comment: Escape won't do what it's currently set to do in the keybindings. It's just grayed out, like you see above.

Comment: @spugsley: It's greyed out because, AFAIK, escape can only be bound to the game menu, and the only valid binding for the game menu is escape.  Asking why that is gets into ask the dev territory, but it is probably because escape, at least in the past, generated a special interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, greyed out infers the option is locked in.

From what the screen is showing me, in your case it is not that the escape button is not mapped to the function, it just won't let you replace the binding with another.

This is common, given the escape buttons function can be more heavily rooted in then that of a spell binding, or menu shortcut.

If you are pressing escape, and it is not taking you to the main menu, or cancelling you out of menus, your problem does not appear to be in the key bindings.